# I need to run a google docs script Mon-Fri at 10:30: suggestions please?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a script that runs on a Google Docs spreadsheet and works fine.
I need to automate the running of this script and have used a trigger,
which also works fine.  In the options for triggers, I can run the
script at 10 to 11 or 11 to 12, but not 10:30.

I can use the exact time option, but that means resetting the date each time.
I could also run it at 10am and put a sleep command in, but not sure if
there is a time restriction on how long a script should run for: this would
effectively run for 30 mins.

Any other thoughts please?

Thanks
Ade

Answer (score 4):

Setting the trigger by script seems to give more options than the UI, see the ClockTriggerBuilder https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_clocktriggerbuilder

eg

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myTimeTrigger")
  .timeBased()
  .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
  .atHour(12).nearMinute(15)
  .create();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am unsure where to actually put this code.

Comment: I have changed that to the following:
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myTimeTrigger")
  .timeBased()
  .everyDays(1)
  .atHour(10).nearMinute(35)
  .create();

But do I add it to the start of the script or create a new function for it? Normally I can work these things out but I need a higher view to get me going :)

Thanks David

Comment: I have not done this but it seems to me that you need a 'first time through execution' eg "if no triggers add this one then exit" at the start of your script.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a trigger every 30 minutes and check in the script itself 'what time is it ?'
not 10:30 ? then return...
depending on the accuracy you need to get it can be tricky to give it a good start... so you could do the same on a minute trigger...
(forget the sleep option, it should be more than total acceptable run time)
See also this post that was quite similar: [Working hours only trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995308/working-hours-only-trigger)

Comment: I thought so on the run time. I'll try the manual on mentioned above next.
thanks Serge