# Time-Driven Trigger to run every X minutes during a given time period?

Tags: timeout, google-apps-script

I have a script that I have to run every 10 minutes but only during say 1AM - 2AM Local time.

Long story short; the script updates about 80+ internal Google Spreadsheets but it must only do this during the hours mentioned above so the chance of a user being in a spreadsheet doing work at the time is almost zero.

I've looked at the Time-Driven Triggers and it has both the functions (to run every 10 minutes and also to run between 1am-2am) however I need to fuse these two triggers together.

Is this possible?

Comment: This has been answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995308/working-hours-only-trigger/10995530#10995530), there are 2 possible ways to do it...
I'm not going to rephrase the answer :-)

Comment: I'm not quite following because in that thread; a "primary" function must be run in order to prompt the user to run the function or automatically run the function. I'm looking for something that triggers by itself at a certain time (1am say). I'm a little confused as to how that particular thread answers my problem :(

Comment: Oh wait, no I get it! I just read another one of your posts and I can make this 'primary function' trigger every hour and to check if it's "1am" then if so; run the rest of my code :)