# Is it possible to set up a clock trigger in Google Apps to send spreadsheet hourly?

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that logs incoming answered and missed calls in Google Drive.
It is currently set to send an email every hour between 10am and 7pm.

Ideally I would like it to not send the email during the weekend.
Setting up each hour Monday to Friday uses too many triggers.

Is there a way to construct a trigger that will send an email every hour (10am to 7pm) only Monday to Friday?

I've read the documentation at Google and a few (unrelated as it turns out) examples on here and I am stumped!

I tried putting a load of trigger conditions together:

```
function autoSendHourly() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger("hourlyUpdate()")
   .timeBased()
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY)
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY)
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY)
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
   .atHour(10)
   .atHour(11)
   .atHour(12)
   .atHour(13)
   .atHour(14)
   .atHour(15)
   .atHour(16)
   .atHour(17)
   .atHour(18)
   .atHour(19)
   .create();
}
```

I wasn't entirely surprised that it didn't work, but I was mildly surprised that it threw up no errors.

Any help (including "you're mad it can't be done") would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is use the create trigger like you did but for every hour every day and then in you handler function add a small piece of code that will return if day and time don't meet specific conditions like explained in [this (old) post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995308/working-hours-only-trigger/10995530#10995530).

the code may look like something like this :

```
function officeHours(){
  var nowH=new Date().getHours();
  var nowD=new Date().getDay();
  Logger.log('day : '+nowD+'   Hours : '+nowH)
  if(nowH>17||nowH<8||nowD==6||nowD==0){return}
  Browser.msgBox('time to work !');//normally your real function should begin here...
}
```

Comment: I had just come to that conclusion myself. I made the mistake of just fixating on trying to use triggers rather than doing the sensible thing.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't messed around with java in awhile but this article might help.

[Android: how to get the current day of the week (Monday, etc...) in the user's language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651221/android-how-to-get-the-current-day-of-the-week-monday-etc-in-user-languag)

If it was me, I would get the day of the week and check it in a switch. Then if it matches a week day call a function to check the time between 10am and 7pm.

Best of luck.